# How to bind NSArrayController to NSManagedObjectContext when using MagicalRecord

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller, magicalrecord

Ive recently started migrating a project to MagicalRecord and cant find how i would bind it to an NSArrayController in the interface builder of XCode 4.

The approach ive taken so far (besides lots of google) is making a reference to the [MagicalRecord defaultContext] and binding to that but i get an error: "Cannot perform operation without a managed object context"

Any pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you properly set up the MagicalRecord in the app delegate?

Comment: I had, but sound advice thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you turn on MagicalRecord as mentioned in the comment. You *may* also have to make a property in your app delegate that exposes the default managed object context provided by MagicalRecord:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) applicationContext;
{
    return [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
}
```

This is so that binding has something to hold onto...though I've not used it in that scenario myself. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you on this, its actually what i did in the end so thank you.