# NSPersistentDocument and NSArrayController with MagicalRecord

Tags: cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord, nspersistentdocument

I have a project where I use Core Data with bindings to NSArrayControllers. I found MagicalRecord and started to implement it.

My question is, how do I implement MagicalRecord without having an AppDelegate? Or Shall I create my own AppDelegate and implement it there?

Thanks in advance,
Mikael

Comment: No, I didn't. Will post here if I do.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059896/how-to-bind-nsarraycontroller-to-nsmanagedobjectcontext-when-using-magicalrecord

Answer (score 0):

MagicalRecord doesn't *require* that you initialise it from an AppDelegate — it's just a convenient spot to do it (and where Apple puts the boilerplate for setting up Core Data in the default templates).

Really, so long as the initialisation happens somewhere nice and early, and before multiple resources go looking for managed objects or their contexts, you can put set it up anywhere.